# regex to capture three strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get three results from a string used to format numbers.

```
var reg = /[0#-,().]+/;
var str = 'Label1(##,###.00)Label2';        
var f = regex.exec(str)[0];
```

This will match the `(##,###.00)` but I would also like to have `Label1` and `Label2` captured if they exist. It would be ideal if the regex always returned an array of three if it's possible.

There will always be part of the string that will match the characters `0#-,().`. Also one special case would be `Label1(##,###.00)Label2(00)`, where the second `(00)` set of characters would be part of the label `Label2(00)`

Some more examples of the input string. I have three variables I'm trying to fill called **left**, **right** and **format**.

```
0            : left = '', right = '', format = '0'
0.00         : left = '', right = '', format = '0.00'
##.00        : left = '', right = '', format = '##.00'
(0.0)        : left = '', right = '', format = '(0.0)'
RandomText##.00                  : left = 'RandomText', right = '', format = '##.00'
RandomText#,###.00MoreRandomText : left = 'RandomText', right = 'MoreRandomText', format = '#,###.00'
```

Comment: I don't get what you're asking? Could you provide some more sample inputs?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var reg = /(Label\d)([0#-,().]+)(Label\d([0#-,().]+)?)/
```

You'll get three capture groups, the first and third would be Label followed by a number, the last one would be your character set again optionally as part of the label, (I'm assuming it is the same character set)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  var regex = /(Label1(\(\d+\))?)([0#-,().]+)(Label2(\(\d+\))?)/;
```

It will also capture the special case you mentioned for Label1.
You can try this on 
[online regex tester](http://regexpal.com/)

With string: "Label1(111)(##,###.00)Label2(00)" (without the '/' in regex)